# PHP PDO Prepared Statements sometimes not working

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm switching my MySQL queries to PDO prepared statements. Most of my queries work but this one just won't work.  It breaks right after the 'prepare' method.

What do you think is wrong?

```
function get_users_days($item_ID, $user_ID)
{
    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    $SQL = "SELECT *
            FROM schedule 
            WHERE item_ID=:item_ID AND user_ID=:user_ID AND end_date>=:today";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $stmt->bindParam(':item_ID', $item_ID);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_ID', $user_ID);
    $stmt->bindParam(':today', $today);

    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
      // do magical things
    }
}
```

Comment: Breaks how? Add an error message?  Just a guess - is `$dbh` being passed in, or is it a global?

Comment: Show us the error,if you get one!

Comment: thanks for the quick responses, $dbh is being defined in an included page (is that ok to do it that way?).  I've also been trying to figure out how to echo the error message, I've tried $stmt->error and $dbh->error, how do you do it?

Comment: ..and it breaks as in the page just stops loading at that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add 
`global $dbh;`  before your `$today` variable

Comment: dude totally, i just grabbed a beer and it hit me.  Just like therefromhere was getting at.  duh!  thanks guys appreciate the quick help.

Comment: Gross. Please pass $dbh into the function or make it a member of a class on construction. Dependency injection is golden.